# Getting totals based on column info

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reporting

In my report viewer i have a group (officeGroup) which has a table within grouped row by office activity. I Have a column which i want to add the total hours where i will check that the cases column is not 0/null.  I wanted to do something like the following

```
Sum(Fields!Hours.Value) Where cases != 0
```

how can i properly form the expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually realized that in order to resolve this issue is to create a filter to the table (not just the row) and make sure that the totals row is included in the table but not in a group. Once that was done, just used the Sum(Fields!Hours.Value) and it worked.